# parseKml() error

Tags: parsing, google-earth-plugin

I have noticed that parseKml() function does not parse KML file correctly. For example, if you have this bit of KML:

```
<ExtendedData>
  <Data name="Offer">
    <value>Apples</value>
    <value>Potatoes</value>
    <value>Tomatoes</value>
  </Data>
</ExtendedData>
```

The parseKml() function will return a kmlObject that will contain only the last value, i.e. "Tomatoes":

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The structure for the type of extended data you are using is for name/value pairs. i.e. a single name with a single value.

```
<ExtendedData>                       
  <Data name="string">
    <displayName>...</displayName>    <!-- string -->
    <value>...</value>                <!-- string -->
  </Data>
</ExtendedData>
```

So what you are trying will not work. If you wish to add an arbitrary XML Data structure to a KML Feature then you would do it like this.

```
<ExtendedData xmlns:offer="http://yourserver.com/namespace">
  <offer:item>Apples</offer:item>
  <offer:item>Potatoes</offer:item>
  <offer:item>Tomatoes</offer:item>
</ExtendedData>
```

Based on the data structure, the 'offer' XML Schema file (http://yourserver.com/namespace) would be something like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="item" type="xsd:string" />
</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `<Data>` element can only contain a single `<value>` - according to the docs, the "`<Data>` element allows you to add untyped name/value pairs to the user data associated with a given Feature."

So in your case, it's picking up the last `<value>` element only. You might find another way to add your custom data here: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/extendeddata